# Check TCP offload is disabled for all the active NIC connections both at OS level & also in righclick properties for each NIC in devmgmt.msc

Tags: arrays, powershell

I wanted some help in making a script for toCheck that the TCP offload is disabled for all the active NIC connections both at OS level & also in righclick properties for each NIC in devmgmt.msc, using powershell.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script I created a while ago to check for TCP offload by looking the various registry keys:

```
param ($computer)
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(‘LocalMachine’,$computer)
$regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey(“SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters”)
new-object psobject | add-member -pass NoteProperty computer $computer |
add-member -pass NoteProperty EnableTCPA $regKey.GetValue(‘EnableTCPA’) |
add-member -pass NoteProperty EnableRSS $regKey.GetValue(‘EnableRSS’) |
add-member -pass NoteProperty EnableTCPChimney $regKey.GetValue(‘EnableTCPChimney’)
```

Here's a link to the blog post:
http://sev17.com/2009/02/check-for-windows-server-2003-scalable-networking-pack/

Comment: Thanks @Chad Miller, some one gave me a -ve vote on question eventhough it had a solution from you.. thanks

Comment: No problem. I thought that was odd too. We've had issues with TOE being enabled in our environment and this script helped. I voted your question up :)